# Jsf 2 PreRenderViewEvent UiViewRoot empty

Tags: jsf-2

I have registered a `SystemEventListener` for the `PreRenderViewEvent`, the purpose of which is to set some components to rendered --> false based on a ui role map.  When a page loads for the first time , the `UiViewRoot` I get from `event.getSource` has no children, although it has the right viewId. On a subsequent call, whenever an event is called from the page , the `UiViewRoot` is populated , and the listener works as expected (the desired components disappear from the page).

Any insight on why it works like that? I thought the expected behavior for `PreRenderViewEvent` was to build  the component tree before the listener is called.

(p.s. running on Mojarra , with the VDL disabled)

Comment: It should indeed be built before PreRenderView event, this is normally performed via `ViewDeclarationLanguage#buildView()`, however you said that you've disabled the VDL. How did you expect that the view get built? Why did you disable the VDL? How does your application work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It's the first phase of the migration for a big application.The idea is to start using some of the features of Jsf 2(bean annotations, view scope etc) , but retain the Jsf 1.2 syntax so as to rewrite as little code as currently possible.  I had seen in the documentation that the ViewDeclarationLanguage is responsible for building the view, but since the listener worked from the second time onward, I was hoping there could be some sort of workaround. It's one of my major concerns right now, along with reconfiguring spring webflow security tags to work in the new setup.

Comment: It probably needs to be said that I am also using richfaces 3.3.3, which requires <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>